# how to get columns name while using applymap with lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have list of variables (columns list) with valid min/max value in one dataframe and values of these variable as columns in another dataframe. I just want to get return flag 0/1 which are in range.

```
def valid_min_max(value):
    valid_min = var_info[var_info.var_name == <column_name>][['valid_min']].values
    valid_max = var_info[var_info.var_name == <column_name>][['valid_max']].values
    if value >= valid_min and value <= valid_max:
        default = 0
    else:
        default = 1
    return default

df_58var[['a','b']].applymap(lambda x : valid_min_max(x))
```

I want "column_name" value dynamically.

Comment: Samples of your inputs and desired output would help

Comment: This can be vectorized, please provide a sample input/desired output.  Read [mcve]

Comment: Why not pass the column name to the function? You can get the columns using `df.columns`

Comment: @Michael you still wouldn't know which column the `.applymap` was currently executing on...

Comment: @JonClements Yes true, thank you. I do not fully understand what he wants. Providing an example would be very helpful.